# management permissions for chrome extension in content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an chrome extension that should check whether another extension and add a div to every web page in `my-website.com` if it is not. So i put this in the manifest:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://my-website.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": true
    }
],

"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "management",
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
]
```

And have this in my content script:

```
chrome.management.getAll(function (apps) {
   /* Manipulate DOM */
});
```

But I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined
```

On the web page. However when I open the dev tools of the extension (chrome://extensions -> background.js) I can use `chrome.management` just fine. How can I use `chrome.management` (or do something equivalent) on the content script?

Comment: I think u missed something in the question!!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I refined the question a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something possible is that your content script ask the background script for getting the list of apps installed.

Put it in your content script.

```
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({messageName: 'getAllApps'}, function(apps) {
// do what you want in with the apps list
});
```

and in your background script listen the request and return the list of apps

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
           if(message.messageName === 'getAllApps') {
             chrome.management.getAll(function (apps) {
                 sendResponse(apps); 
             });
           }
        }
 );
```

---

**Edit**

Like it is said in the comment of the post, content script have a limited access to chrome api [See HERE](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), that is why the only solution for you is to communicate with the background script which have access to everything.

Comment: You should emphasize in your answer that Content Scripts [have limited access to Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).